# Implementing Google Login in Swift code

Tags: oauth, client, swift

I am trying to insert the code for google OAuth, the client ID in Swift code. 
Manual simply said "add it to controller"

I am not sure how to write this line in Swift and in which location of Swift project.

```
static NSString * const kClientId = @"YOUR_CLIENT_ID";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Swift equivalent of that would essentially be a global constant `String`. Put this at the top level in whichever file makes sense, and it will be available within any Swift function, class or method in your project:

```
let kClientId = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID"
```